# Why does the child's resolve function not contain the result of the parent's resolve function?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I've tried to isolate this example and I hope it's ok. I know, this isn't great code, but I hope you get the drift.

For the time being the resolvers return a static result object.

Here's my problem:

The result of the company resolve function should be passed on the user's resolve function. But that ain't happenin' and I wonder what I am missing.

```js
const GraphQL = require('graphql');

const UserType = new GraphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: {
    givenName: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLString },
    familyName: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLString },
    city: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLString },
  },
});

const CompanyType = new GraphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Company',
  fields: {
    legalName: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLString },
    city: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLString },
    employees: { type: new GraphQL.GraphQLList(UserType) },
  },
});

const queryDef = new GraphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        id: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLID },
        givenName: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLString },
        familyName: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLString },
        city: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLString },
      },
      resolve: (parent, args, context, info) => {
        console.log('parent should provide company object', parent);
        // currentyl parent is undefined
        return {
          id: 10,
          givenName: 'test',
        };
      },
    },
    company: {
      type: CompanyType,
      args: {
        id: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLID },
      },
      resolve: (parent, args, context, info) => {
        return {
          id: 3,
          legalName: 'legal test name',
          city: 'company location',
        };
      },
    },
  },
});

const schema = new GraphQL.GraphQLSchema({ query: queryDef });

const companyQuery = `
  {
    company(id: 1) { 
      city 
      employees { 
        familyName 
      }  
    } 
  }`;

GraphQL.graphql(schema, companyQuery).then( (companyResult) => {
  console.log(companyResult);
} ).catch( (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: user type resolver != company.employees prop resolver (missing)

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but where would I put that missing resolver? I can't find any documentation on how this is done.

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/execution/ tutorials are for that

Comment: @xadm Using GraphQL's object notation works different than what's described in the documentation example. When using Object the resolvers are put next to the type. That's different from the examples which are addressing GraphQL's schema language, where the resolvers are located in their own object.

The documenation on execution, which you provided, does not cover nested associations in connection with GraphQL's Object notation.

At least I don't see, how that documentation would help me in my case.

Comment: you're answering yourself ... *' the resolvers are put next to the type'* - employees type is defined, where is [your missing] resolver? *'next to type'* ? ... search for tutorial for 'field resolver' [for your server] or example like ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/37606819/6124657

Comment: @xadm I figured it out. I had to place the employees resolver in the fields section of the 'Company' object. I really hadn't expected _that_ to be the location for the resolver, because when using the schema language, on would wouldn't and can't place resolvers in the type defintion.

But that's propably just me. So anyway, thanks for your patience and pointing me into the right direction. You've really helped me a lot.